# Conditional access policy in Azure -> restrict normal users from using azure powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, entra-id

I'm looking for a solution(conditional access policy) or something else that will restrict normal users from accessing azure active directory power shell and execute msol (get-msolgroup) or azure ad cmdlet's.

If someone has a solution please share.

I was looking in internet but could not find anything.

Thank you.

Regards
Aleks

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? If you don't want users querying your AAD then you need to adjust the permissions on AD and your users, stopping them accessing the PowerShell modules isn't going to help.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? - to restrict users from accessing data that they should not be able to view, normal users should be able to use just web UI and not PowerShell.
What you mean by adjust the permissions on AD and users?

Comment: If you don't want normal users to access data from Azure AD, then change permissions in Azure AD so they can't get it. If you want them to be able to access it, then you can't control what medium they use to achieve it. If they can access the data through the web UI then what does it matter if they can also use PowerShell? They can't achieve anything extra.